# How do you obtain the maximum possible date in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, function, date, max

Is there a function built into Oracle that will return the highest possible date that may be inserted into a date field?

Comment: Why ? If you start putting in dummy 'high-date' values into a table, it can 'confuse' the optimizer which will assume that you have a whole range of date values spread over the next 8 thousand years.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
SELECT  TO_DATE('31.12.9999 23:59:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
FROM    dual
```

Note that minimal date is much more simple:

```
SELECT  TO_DATE(1, 'J')
FROM    dual
```

Comment: I think for most people's purposes `TO_DATE('9999', 'yyyy')` would be a much shorter and acceptable alternative, especially when using to coalesce nulls in comparisons.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, but the op asked for "maximum possible date".

Comment: I know. Just adding my 2 cents in hope it helps someone.

Comment: `TO_DATE(1, 'J')` returns 1st of January, the current year for me?

Comment: @RichardDingwall: for everyone else, it does not. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ce59/2

Comment: TO_DATE(1, 'J') returned January, 01 4713 00:00:00-0800 for me in sqlfiddle

Comment: `SELECT to_char(TO_DATE('31.12.9999 23:59:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'J') FROM dual;` would give `5373484`. Hence the second query should be `SELECT to_date(5373484, 'J') FROM dual;`.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: have you by any chance noticed it says "miminal date"?

Comment: @Quassnoi, completely missed it, apologies. I need a coffee break. I never expected a completely opposite solution. Question is about maximum date value, so  why did you provide an opposite solution? Jusr curious.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: no probs. I provided both, just in case.

Answer (score 8):

From the 11g docs:

Oracle Database can store dates in the Julian era, ranging from January 1, 4712 BCE through December 31, 9999 CE (Common Era, or 'AD').

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847

Comment: Common Era... Is that a politically correct term for the "confessionally biased" AD ?

Comment: Real answer to the question... Jan 1 4712 till Dec 31 9999

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of a function but according to [this article](http://www.ss64.com/orasyntax/datatypes.html):

> **Oracle 7:** from January 1, 4712 BC to December 31, 4712 AD.
>   **Oracle 8:** from January 1, 4712 BC to December 31, 9999 AD.
>   **Oracle 9:** from January 1, 4712 BC to December 31, 9999 AD.
>   **PL/SQL:** from January 1, 4712 BC to December 31, 9999 AD.

Answer (score 2):

Another ways, just for fun:

```
SELECT to_date(5373484, 'J') + (1 - 1/24/60/60)
  FROM dual;

SELECT date '9999-12-31' + (1 - 1/24/60/60) 
  FROM dual;
```

Comment: The first query should be `SELECT to_date(5373484, 'J') + (1 - 1/24/60/60) FROM dual;`

Answer (score 0):

In Julian format (JDDD) the max Oracle date is 2086307365.