# Replacement of DateTime.MinValue in C# to sql

Tags: c#, oracle

In C#, I have using linq ,in which i consumed DateTime of Min value.
I am going to convert this query in oracle.

```
select x 
from x in Context.GetRolePlansQuery(AppResources.CurrentUser.Role.RoleId,
                                                                   AppResources.CurrentUser.Loginid,
                                                                   AppResources.CurrentUser.Tpa.TpaId) where
x.LAST_STAGE_COMPLETE.ToUpper() == "RECEIVED"
orderby (x.CDC_COMPLETE_DATE.HasValue ? x.CDC_COMPLETE_DATE : DateTime.MinValue) descending
select x
```

I want to know the server datetime of Min value in oracle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/687533/342740

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a fair understanding of the range of values of oracle sql server data types:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#i54330

**However, there is a difference in the min value of the .net object and the sql server data type, the min value of DateTime.MinValue is 0001/1/1.**