# How to insert data from text file where date column has date as "00-00-0000"

Tags: sqlplus, toad, oracle9i

I have a text file and it contains one column as "NPA_DATE", in which few rows contain date as "00-00-000".

I am unable to load data where date is in "00-00-0000" format. I am getting the error as "Record 1: Rejected - Error on table MIS_PNPA, column NPA_DATE. ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month". However I want to load the data with NPA_DATE as "00-00-0000" along with other data. All other rows are getting uploaded in database. I use toad for oracle 9.0.1.8

Comment: 00 is a invalid date and month. Why don't you replace  "00-00-0000"  with null or [minimum date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687510/how-do-you-obtain-the-maximum-possible-date-in-oracle)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Knu8, however please let me know how to replace date "00-00-0000' by null in control file (.ctl) as it is a daily process  to truncate the table and insert the new/updated data in table.  My ctl file is 
LOAD DATA
INTO TABLE mis_pnpa
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(sr_no,branch_code,account_no,name1,acct_type,int_cat,product_name,appv_amt,adv_amt,theo_bal,out_amt,srf_amt,security_amt,arrear,inca,uipy,act_outstand,npa_date date 'DD-MM-YYYY',old_irac,new_irac,arrear_cond,sys,proc_date date 'DD/MM/YYYY')

Comment: Why dont you replace "00-00-0000' with null in the text file itself.

Comment: Dear Knu8, I have done the automation of updating the database on daily basis. Almost 20 tables gets updated on daily basis by .bat file. If it has been a one time exercise I would have replaced it in text file but its an ongoing process which will happen daily. So if some code is there which we can put in control file (.ctl), so that it can be uploaded on daily basis via automation.

Comment: I am pretty much sure that you can write code to replace some text in .txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the SQLPlus tag to your original post as this is really a SQLPlus question.

Anyway alter your control file to this to set the date to NULL if it comes in as '00-00-0000' in the data file:

```
...
npa_date date "DD-MM-YYYY" NULLIF (npa_date="00-00-0000")
...
```