# Input year in the specified range

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a query and apple CASE funcation and getting error

> (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

This code is yielding the error:

```
NVL(     
CASE WHEN Ea.ASGACTSTART < add_months(SYSDATE,-12)  THEN 365
ELSE 
to_number( to_char(to_date('1','J') +
((SYSDATE -1) - Ea.ASGACTSTART), 'J') )
END , 0)  "Adujsted Days",
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `to_number( to_char(to_date('1','J')`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply make

```
CASE WHEN Ea.ASGACTSTART < add_months(SYSDATE,-12)  THEN 365
ELSE NVL(SYSDATE - 1 - Ea.ASGACTSTART, 0)
END AS "Adujsted Days"
```

Comment: What is a "single value"? Surround it by `TRUNC()` or `ROUND()` if needed.

Comment: Thanks 
i have formula in Excel but i dont need any formula in Excel is there anything that i convert excel formula to in Oracel Query here is the Excel formula



=+IF(ISBLANK(@Enddate),IF($StartDate <Today()-1,365,Today()-1-startdate+1),MAX(MIN(today()-1+1,Startdate+1),DATE(YEAR(C1)-1, MONTH(C1), DAY(C1)))-MIN(MAX(DATE(YEAR(C1)-1, MONTH(C1), DAY(C1)),Startdate),today()-1+1))

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
create table tabby (ASGACTSTART date);
insert into tabby values (sysdate);
```

The problem is this part of your expression:

```
select 
   to_date('1','J') + ((SYSDATE -1) - Ea.ASGACTSTART)
from tabby ea;
```

If you change the `+` to `,` then you can see why it's a problem.

```
select 
   --to_date('1','J') + ((SYSDATE -1) - Ea.ASGACTSTART)
     to_date('1','J') , ((SYSDATE -1) - Ea.ASGACTSTART)
from tabby ea;
```

According to at least [one other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687510/how-do-you-obtain-the-maximum-possible-date-in-oracle), to_date('1','J') is intended to return the smallest possible date possible. However, the right-hand side of the `+` might be negative and therefore cause the RDBMS to complain.

The use case I created was intended to do just that.

Comment: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got DATE JULIAN